# Python import class simple example error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wonder why my simple example building a class is not properly working:

The tree-structure looks like the following

```
class_project/
├── class_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── classtheclass.py
└── tests 
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test.py
```

classtheclass.py looks like this:

```
class ClassTheClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "yeees"
```

test.py looks like this:

```
from class_project.classtheclass import ClassTheClass


i = ClassTheClass()
```

While **init**.py are empty

so if i execute on the shell

> python test.py

its giving me

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from class_project.classtheclass import ClassTheClass ImportError: No module named class_project.classtheclass

Whats wrong with that. In Pycharm this even works...!

Comment: Have you tried: `from classtheclass import ClassTheClass`?

Comment: Put the test.py inside class_project(behind tests), execute test.py and it will able to access the class classtheclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `python test.py`, the interpreter will look for Python code in standard library locations (e.g. `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and friends) and in the `tests` folder where you invoked the interpreter (this set of locations is known as the "Python Path", and you can view it with: `import sys; print sys.path`).

None of those locations include `class_project.classtheclass`.

There are a variety of ways to solve this problem.

You can set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include `class_project`:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/class_project:$PYTHONPATH"  # Note: this has to be the top-level class_project directory, you have two with this name here.
python test.py  # This will now work
```

---

You could probably also use a relative import, but I'd argue that's working around the problem not solving the problem.

Comment: ah i see... do you know how to manage that with virtualenv? But if eim on top level the same error appears when calling  python tests/test.py

Comment: @Jurudocs You could add `export ...` to the bottom of your `activate` script. I wouldn't recommend it though. This isn't typically something you'd expect (or need) virtualenv to take care of. Eventually you'll just use a test runner (or an IDE) to do this for you anyway. It might seem cumbersome right now, but you'll eventually find out this is a non-problem.

Comment: hmm okay i will run the tests with ansible on remote servers...thats why i thought i would need it

Comment: is there a more elegant solution you can think of?

Answer (score 1):

Your file tree structure is wrong, if you are not exporting PYTHONPATH with the new lib path, you have to put the `test.py` as below structure to make the test.py to access classtheclass from class_project.

```
class_project/
├── class_project
│   ├── classtheclass.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── test.py
```

Comment: do you have tests on the project level normally?

Answer (score 0):

Python search imported module as follow, for example `import foo`

- Firstly, search the `built-in` module, If `foo` isn't a `built-in` module, go to next
- Interpreter will search the `sys.path`, `sys.path` will include: current directory, `PYTHONPATH` and installation dependent path. If `foo` is in `sys.path`, it will be imported. Otherwise, it will be `ImportError`.

Here, you can execute at project parent directory or explicit add `/path/to/project` to `sys.path`.